# How to pick top line of each group of related lines with awk after Unix sort

Tags: unix, sorting, awk

I have the following data (in actual case there are ~1M lines)

```
foo qux 0 x,y
bar twe 1 a,b,c
foo qux 2 x,y,z
```

What I want to do is to sort it by first field
and when there is a tie pick one with highest value of the 3rd fields.
Yielding:

```
bar twe 1 a,b,c
foo qux 2 x,y,z
```

But why doesn't this code work?

```
   sort -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3nr datafile.txt |
   awk '$3 != x {print} {x = $3}'   
   # The last awk line attempts to pick top from tie
```

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: Title says `SED`, body says `awk`? You sure you know what you want. Besides to _unconditionally_ pick the first line of a text use `head -1`.

Comment: @Christian.K: Thanks. Title corrected. Still, this is not an _unconditional_ pick.

Comment: It's not that clear what you are trying to do. How do you want to handle ties in both the first and third fields?

Comment: @neversaint I know it is not unconditional, hence I've only written it as a comment, not an answer. Thanks for correcting/clarifying the title though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your command is close to correct, but you need to break on `$1`, not `$3`.  Also, your statement is that you need to sort on first and then third field, but the code is sorting by first, then second, then third field.

Nominally, then, you need:

```
sort -k1,1 -k3,3nr datafile.txt | awk '$1 != x { print } { x = $1 }'
```

If you need to break on first and second fields (and sort on them), then:

```
sort -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3nr datafile.txt |
awk '$1 != x || $2 != y { print } { x = $1; y = $2; }'
```

Comment: You should sort the third field as numbers, as far I understand the question.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber: Yup; it doesn't matter in the sample data, but I've fixed the examples.  Transcription error...

Answer (score 0):

```
sort -k1,1rn <your_file>|awk '{a[$1]=$0;}END{for(i in a)print a[i]}'
```